# System.Web.HttpContext.Current.get returned null in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use Session in an action of my MVC controller but I encountered this error but I'm not sure why the error is coming out.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.get returned null.
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using fyp.Models;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace fyp.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        //Omitted actions

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult StartOrderMenu()
        {
            ViewData["Layout"] = "_Layout";
            List<Cart> carts = new List<Cart>();
            var jsoncart = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(carts);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["cart"] = jsoncart;
            DbSet<Food> dbs = _dbContext.Food;
            List<Food> model = dbs.ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply assign `Session["cart"] = jsoncart;` will work because it comes from `Controller` class. The `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` instance may having no context at the time you're using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto if I use `Session["cart"] = jsoncart;` I will get `The name 'Session' does not exists in the current context`

Comment: Sorry, I'm forgot you're using Core MVC. The `Session` usage is slightly different because `System.Web` namespace not exist (see [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1)): `HttpContext.Session.SetString("cart", jsoncart);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.Web` namespace is not used in ASP.NET Core MVC, hence `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` property will always return null value (note that `HttpContext` is injected). If you want to set session variable in `IActionResult` controller, you can use [`SessionExtensions.SetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.setstring?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method:

```
string key = "cart";

HttpContext.Session.SetString(key, jsoncart);
```

If you want to retrieve it, use [`SessionExtensions.GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.getstring?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method:

```
string jsonCart = HttpContext.Session.GetString("cart");
```

**Note:** To get `HttpContext` instance work, put `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` before namespace declaration.

Further reference: [Session and app state in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1)